# What is the word for "many young people"?

Tags: word-choice

I am looking for a substitute word for "many young people" in the sentence "Many young people are willing to get vaccinated"

Comment: Possibly "youngsters", though that usually would mean under 10 or so.

Comment: I am looking for people from 18-35 or else

Comment: what about " lots youths"?

Comment: I don't know of any single words.  "Many youth" would work if the people you're talking about are teenagers or kids.  18-35?  But I don't think there is a word for that age group.   "Many young adults" is close but most people wouldn't think it extends all the way up to age 35.

Comment: I don't think there is a word meaning **many** AND an age-range! You might say "Many 18 to 35-year-olds." Or, if it's already clear from the context that you are talking about _adults_, you could say, "Many born since 1985" or "Many under 36's". Or "many of the post-Live Aid (or post-Brixton Riot) generation." Would [cohort](https://www.lexico.com/definition/cohort) be useful?